# Domain Driven Design How to display audited attributes in different bounded contexts?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, audit-trail

We currently working on a large project that contains a lot of Bounded Contexts, one of them used for **Identity and Access Control** and it contains the User, Role entities. After the User logged-in, he can then use any other modules(Bounded Contexts),
My Issue --> we need to display information about the user that create or update data in different bounded context for example, we need to display Audited Attributes e.g. **ModifiedBy**, **CreatedBy** users
I have two solutions in mind for such issues:-

- Share User, Role across Bounded Contexts
- Use optimized SQL views that get aggregate data from bounded contexts
  note that, i use a single database but with different sachems for every bounded context

Comment: it's quite normal to share users and roles across modules. I'm not sure what the issue is here? Does that not fully meet your needs?

Comment: @yo2011 is this information supposed to be in sync with the Identity BC at all times or is it a snapshot of the user at the time the action was performed (which should be way simpler to implement)?

Comment: @ guillaume31 it should be in sync every time

Answer (score 2):

In DDD, when you need to use models (like Users) from one bounded context (BC) to another bounded context you should use an [Anti-corruption layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer). This means that you may not simply use the same model but a simplified one, i.e with fewer attributes and it must be immutable (readonly).

So, if the User is an Entity in the IAC BC, with many properties and behaviors (read and write), in the Remote BC it is a [Value object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html), i.e. with only its `ID` and `Name` as read-only properties. The ACL has the responsibility of translating from an remote Entity to a local Value object that can be *safely* used in the local BC.

Depending on your architecture, the ACL can be implemented using a `CRON` job, be periodically updating local Value objects from remote Entities or can react to the remote events in case of event-driven architectures (CQRS, Event sourcing). You can even tail the remote database's [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) to have nearly instantaneous updates.

So, every BC should have its own data and the services that live in it should be able to function independently. If the services in one BC go down, the services in the other BC should continue to work. Think of BCs as modules.

Some see the User Interface as a different BC. So, in this case, the `optimized SQL views` could live in this separate BC and act as a model with a built-in ACL. It cannot however function separately. It also couples the other BCs together, by forcing you to use the same database type or even instance in all the BCs.